¿Como aplicar los keyframes de anime.js en A-Frame?
En este ejemplo, podemos ver como funcionan los keyframes en anime.js.
Inspirado por este otro ejemplo:


var anime = AFRAME.ANIME; // grab the anime reference
anime({
  targets: 'a-sphere',    // a CSS selector of the sphere
  radius: 2,              // the attribute that is supposed to be changed
  direction: 'alternate', // alternate direction
  loop: true,             // loop the animation
  easing: 'linear'
})
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" scale="8 8 8" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>



extraida de esta respuesta en inglés y inspirado en la documentación en inglés de A-Frame, he intentado aplicarlo con el siguiente código sin éxito:
/* global AFRAME */

AFRAME.registerComponent('animation-test', {
    schema: {

    },

    init: function () {
        this.el.setAttribute('animation__001', {
            'property': 'position',
            // 'to': { x: -0.47, y: 1.73, z: -0.3 },
            'keyframes': [
                { x: -0.47, y: 1.63, z: -0.5 },
                { x: -0.47, y: 1.73, z: -0.5 },
                { x: -0.47, y: 1.73, z: -0.3 },
            ],
            'duration': 4000,
            'startEvents': 'startanim001'
        });
        this.el.emit('startanim001', null, false);
    },

Esperaba que la animación durara 4 segundos y en ese tiempo el objeto se moviera a diferentes coordenadas.
¿O hay otra forma de usar keyframes?
Gracias por adelantado.
